# Django File Field : Audio File is not forwarding and rewinding

Tags: javascript, django, audio

Well I don't even know that is it a django problem or not but can you please help me I have following field in my model.

```
url = models.FileField(upload_to='music', null=True)
```

I have no problem uploading the file.
in my API - I'm getting the url of the file which I'm uploading.
but even if directly open it from link in the browser I face the same problem.
I guess it's not loading the meta data of the file first. but what should I do.

[image]

on the server I get `Broken pipe from ('127.0.0.1', 51658)`

Comment: Please add a [mre] to your question. How do you upload the file? You say "_when I use it with javascript I'm not able to forward it or rewind it_" again how do you do this?

Comment: thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat but the problem is not with with javascript. I'm playing with HTML audio Element. and it works fine when I Play a local file. but the server file is not loading meta deta. leave javascript it's not even forwarding and rewinding on brower directly with server url. I get the URL `: "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/music/yt1s.com_-_Bhaja_Govindam.mp3"`,